# ActiveMQ/HornetQ p2p is polling-based or pushing-based model

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, hornetq

What happens behind the scene, when receiving messages with (spring or ejb) message listener container in ActiveMQ/HornetQ?

1. Does broker pushing messages to consumers? If so, how consumers register
   themselves to broker?
2. Or consumers polling messages on the queue? If so, why each queue (in admin console) has a consumer-number field that shows number of registered consumers of the queue?

[This link](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/ejb3_ch13/?page=4) of O'Reilly book said:

> The p2p messaging model has traditionally been a pull- or
>   polling-based model, where messages are requested from the queue
>   instead of being pushed to the client automatically. (**The JMS
>   specification does not specifically state how the p2p and pub/sub
>   models must be implemented.** Either one may use push or pull, but at
>   least conceptually pub/sub is push and p2p is pull).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not stating the protocol, since ActiveMQ and HornetQ are multi protocol brokers the exact implementation may vary a bit. However, most protocols except HTTP/REST based ones pushes messages to the client. It's not possible to achive high throughput without a push strategy on the wire protocol level.

The application level API allows for "polling", i.e. JMS [MessageConsumer.receive](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive(long)), but that's really just a "sleep until a message is pushed" mechanism.